# Simplify String exception checks

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, winforms, try-catch

In my code I will run a process and retrieve part of the standard error output (a number) to raise an event which send a progress number.

Sometimes I have an exception at this line at ".First" method 'cause the string has nothing to split:

```
out = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadLine.Trim.Split("%").First
```

The problem Is I want to add the necessary check to avoid that exception without doing a Try/Catch because in my speed tests I've noticed that a try/catch in this procedure will slow the performance a lot.

I want to simplify the code doing the necessary checks but without a catching any exception (By the moment the checks I've added would be executed quickly than a try/catch).

Here is the code:

```
Private Shared Sub Run_MP3Gain_NotTag()

    mp3gain_For_NonTag.Start() ' Run process

    Dim out as string  = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadToEnd

    While Not mp3gain_For_NonTag.HasExited

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(out) Then
            ' This would generate numbers between 1 to 100
            out = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadLine.Trim.Split("%").First
        End If

        If Integer.TryParse(out, 0) Then
            RaiseEvent MP3Gain_Progress(out)
        End If

    End While

    RaiseEvent MP3Gain_Exited()

End Sub
```

...And for additional information, this is a sample of what I don't want to do, I can say that adding a try catch like in this modificated code code even without catching any exception kind this will reduce the performance a lot:

```
Private Shared Sub Run_MP3Gain_NotTag()

    mp3gain_For_NonTag.Start() ' Run process

    Dim out as string = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadToEnd 

    While Not mp3gain_For_NonTag.HasExited

        Try
            out = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadLine.Trim.Split("%").First
            RaiseEvent MP3Gain_Progress(out)
        Catch : End Try

    End While

    RaiseEvent MP3Gain_Exited()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your approach looks fine. Apart from that, i guess you should post such questions better on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thanks so much I did not knew that exists a section for Code Reviews.

Comment: First one looks fine to me, too. You are completely correct about not using an exception because out being empty is not exceptional, which is why it would be a performance hit. Can't see any real need to "improve" version 1. What doesn't feel right to you?

Comment: @ElektroHacker: However, i don't understand why you don't include the `TryParse` in the `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(out)`. If it's null or empty it cannot be parsed to `Int32` anyway.

Comment: Maybe the first code looks fine but is not, the string null check that I did fails because Like I try to say sometimes throws an exception trying to split the string

Comment: Avoiding exceptions is a good goal.  But try/catch blocks will generally not hurt performance if no exceptions are thrown. Profiling as needed would verify individual cases.

Comment: Sure guys maybe you have reason and something of what I've said about Try/catch (without catching) maybe is wrong because I'm not a master expert of the language, But on the other hand my speed tests does not lies, the process processes an amount of 80.000 files, only thing what I know is that using a try/catch block instead other checks will reduce the total process execution time from start to end from about 20% more of time and I can notice that is related about the try/catch block because if I delete it I gain that 20% of speed. thankyou all for your comments and forgive my English.

Comment: No one here is arguing that you should use the exception we all agree with you and for the reason you have proven, it's slower. What wasn't clear, at least to me was that you were still getting an exception with the first version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [.FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) might be your answer here.

Took another look at it.  I don't think your problem is the First method.  The exception thrown by First is a symptom.  Your problem is you set `out` by reading to the end of the stream, then you run Split by trying to read another line, which will return nothing, hence the exception.  Just Split `out` and everything should be fine:

```
Dim out as string  = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadToEnd

While Not mp3gain_For_NonTag.HasExited

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(out) Then
        ' This would generate numbers between 1 to 100
        out = out.Trim.Split("%").First()
    End If
```

Comment: That's it, really never used it, I see in the description that it will never throw any exception if has any element to return, thanks I need some minutes to try it to see if it works nice

Answer (score 1):

Check for the index of the split character (`%`) and only do the split if it is found, like this:

```
If out.IndexOf("%") > -1 Then
    ' Do split logic here
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a function that checks the error message for the "%" value and returns an appropriate value.

```
out = ParseError(mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadLine.Trim())

Private Function ParseError(msg As String) As String
    Dim retVal As String = msg
    If msg.Contains("%") Then retVal = msg.Split("%").First
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Stick the result of `ReadLine` into another variable and run String.IsNullOrEmpty() on it, then trim it, run String.IsNullOrEmpty() on it. If you are still OK, split it and do the First on it.  No error and faster than if you let it error and caught it.

```
Dim x as string = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadLine
if Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) then
 x = x.trim
 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) then
  out = x.Split("%").First
 End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try/Catch blocks themselves don't harm performance; it's only when exceptions are actually thrown and caught that performance takes a hit.

That being said, if you can avoid using exceptions entirely, you should certainly do it. In this case, you can easily check if the result of `Split` has at least one element:

```
Dim parts = out = mp3gain_For_NonTag.StandardError.ReadLine.Trim.Split("%")
If parts.Length > 0 Then
    out = parts.First
End If
```

Another option is to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`; it will return `Nothing` if there is no result.

Comment: Thanks so much I need some minutes to test it